# generating list with permuted tuples in a list

Tags: python

How to permute the tuple on a list.

> ```
> A= [(a,b), (c,d), (e, f)]
> ```

If `A` is a list then with permutation tuples, the list are

> ```
>   [(a,b), (c,d), (e, f)]
>   [(a,b), (c,d), (f, e)]
>   [(a,b), (d,c), (e, f)]
>   [(a,b), (d,e), (f, e)]
>   ....
> ```

It has 8 such list.

Comment: You may want to make it a little more obvious that you are not using permutations in the usual sense here; you want to create the *product* of the regular and inverted sublists of `A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with a generator expression to generate the inversions:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> A = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
>>> for perm in product(*((l, l[::-1]) for l in A)):
...     print perm
... 
(('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'))
(('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('f', 'e'))
(('a', 'b'), ('d', 'c'), ('e', 'f'))
(('a', 'b'), ('d', 'c'), ('f', 'e'))
(('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'))
(('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd'), ('f', 'e'))
(('b', 'a'), ('d', 'c'), ('e', 'f'))
(('b', 'a'), ('d', 'c'), ('f', 'e'))
```

The `((l, l[::-1]) for l in A)` generator expression produces 3 arguments to `product()`, each a tuple consisting of both a sublist and the inversion of that sub list of `A`:

```
>>> [(l, l[::-1]) for l in A]
[(('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')), (('c', 'd'), ('d', 'c')), (('e', 'f'), ('f', 'e'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

A = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]

print map(lambda x: zip(*[iter(x)]*2),permutations(chain(*A)))

# Hints:
# chain(*A) => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

# permutations(chain(*A)) => ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), 

#                            ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e'), 

#                            ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f'),
                             ...
# lambda x: zip(*[iter(x)]*2) chunks the iterable by length 2

# [iter(x)]*2 creates a list contains 2 references to a same iterator object.

# The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed.                   
# This makes possible an idiom for clustering a data series 
# into n-lengthgroups using zip(*[iter(s)]*n).
```